# Why can't I get scraped data from a website with BeautifulSoup? I'm getting timeout error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib2, urlopen

I was trying to get data from the following website but I get the error which is shown below. PFB the code for the same.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import bs4 as bs
response = urlopen('http://www.mec.ac.in/mec/stats2018.php')
html = response.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
print soup.title
```

PFB the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "et.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = urlopen('http://www.mec.ac.in/mec/stats2018.php')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

How can I retrieve data after recovering this error?

Comment: You can't, the site is flat out denying you access to the resource.

Comment: I tested the url with request (from requests) and that seems to work just fine (status_code 200)

Comment: Okay thanks for the help

Comment: the server is not allowing you to get this exact URL. 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: The title is misleading with the „timeout error“ where the traceback in the question clearly shows an access permission error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server specifically "blocks" requests with `User-Agent` header containing `Python-urllib` string (which `urllib2`/`urllib` sends by default):

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: url = "http://www.mec.ac.in/mec/stats2018.php"

In [3]: requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Python-urllib/2.6'})
Out[3]: <Response [403]>

In [4]: requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'})
Out[4]: <Response [200]>
```